# How to deal google re-captcha v3 in UI Path

Tags: javascript, uipath

Greeting friends, As I am new to UI path and struggling in the project, I had come to a dead end where i need to fill the google recaptca with some clicks or any technique plus if its ask to solve the challenge then how can I handle this.

Comment: You have to remember that the whole point of the captcha is to PREVENT automated handling, and require a manual input. There are some components which are available on the UiPath Marketplace which try to solve these problems, but there's no guarantee.  Depending on the nature of your project, there may be ways you can arrange to bypass the captcha - but you'd have to provide significantly more information that you have about the project

Comment: UI Path isn't a programming language so the question doesn't belong here. You might be able to find a users forum to post this.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, let me check more details